# Make the equation true by only drawing a single straight line

Tags: mathematics

Fred has a puzzle.  The instruction sheet, which is separate from the equation,simply says:  "Make this equation true.  You may ONLY draw ONE, PERFECTLY straight line".  The equation is all alone on a blank piece of paper and reads:

```
5+5+5=550
```

There are 4 acceptable answers.  You must get all 4 for a correct answer.

Comment: 5 and 6th answer found 5-5+5 not equal 550

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1. > Cross out the equals sign
2. > Turn the first $+$ into a 4 giving $545+5=550$
3. > Turn the second $+$ into a 4 giving $5+545=550$
4. > Turn the equals sign into less than or equal to

Comment: BONUS there is a fourth acceptable answer.  good on you!

Comment: Joe K added the fourth answer but Michal answered all 3 first (when i said i needed 3 answers)

Answer (score 15):

I think the fourth answer, which hasn't been posted yet is:

> $5+5+5≤550$

That makes all of them:

> $5+5+5≤550$
> $545+5=550$
> $5+545=550$
> $5+5+5≠550$

Comment: I was supposed to give you a bounty, but it expired as I was not active due to personal reasons. I'll therefore upvote ten of your answers to give you 100 reputation ;)

Answer (score 10):

> 5+5+5≠550
>  
> negating the equality.
>  
>  Edit:
>  
> You could negate the entire statement, depending on how you interpret the equation...
>  _________
>  5+5+5=550        could evaluate to "true" in some contexts... ^^

Comment: This almost feels like cheating ;-)

Comment: @TheodosiusVonRichthofen umm... You didn't say that

Comment: @TheodosiusVonRichthofen you said there were 3 acceptable answers, and I provided one. Alas, someone already beat me to the other two :p.

Answer (score 4):

I'd put a line

> on one of the plus signs, straight up.
>  The equation would read
>  545 + 5 = 550