# Just One Line! Really?

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

Add **ONLY ONE** line (*does not have to be a straight horizontal line or in other words, doesn't need to be an axis aligned to the equal sign*) to make the equation below true :

> > **EQUATION :**
>
> $5$ $+$ $5$ $+$ $5$ $=$ $555$
>
> > **Notes And Clarification :**
>
> - **Crossing the equal sign is not allowed**
> - **Making a less or more than sign (≤ or ≥) is also not allowed**
> - **This is not a duplicate of [$5$ $+$ $5$ $+$ $5$ $=$ $550$](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4315/make-the-equation-true-by-only-drawing-a-single-straight-line)**
> - **The answer with the most votes will get the green checkmark**

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean "[= 550](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4315/make-the-equation-true-by-only-drawing-a-single-straight-line)"?

Comment: Nope, this is a new one :D @Alconja

Comment: Does the line need to be perfectly straight like it did in the 550 question?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach it doesn't need to be "an axis aligned to the equal sign" :D

Comment: @KevinL In comment to [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/73901/32339) you said "I'm still waiting for others to come up with better ones". Can you state in your puzzle what kind of answer you deem better than others and why?

Comment: @xhienne I meant that the highest answer (apart from GeorgeMenoutis's answer coz that's a clarification) will get the checkmark in the end :D

Comment: Since this question appears to have *many* valid answers with no way to tell which one is the best, it has been closed as too broad.

Comment: @Deusovi True, I didn't realize that there will be lots of different answers :D

Comment: @Kevin, out of curiosity, what was the answer you had in mind?

Comment: @xhienne My answer is just like Simplifire's answer using congruence XD

Comment: @Kevin Too bad, by subsequently adding "does not have to be a straight horizontal line" to your puzzle, you made it too broad. On the contrary, if you had specified "it must be a straight horizontal line", your puzzle would have had a unique solution (yours).

Comment: @xhienne Yea, I guess so but it was still fun making this puzzle :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This equation is true

> ... in base 14:
>
>  $5 + 5 + 5 = 55 / 5$
>
>  (in base 14, 5 + 5 + 5 = 11)

Comment: A really creative answer (+1) :D

Comment: this one is a nice answer really

Comment: Thanks guys, but I'm quite sure this is not the expected answer and I can't help feeling like I'm kind of cheating ;-)

Comment: puzzling is for fun! You can see some really weird solutions around...

Comment: @Vincent 55 in base 14 is equal to 75 in base 10 (ie. 5 x 14 + 5). However, 11 in base 14 is equal to 15 in base 10 (ie. 1 x 14 + 1). Hence in base 14, 55/5 = 11 is true, because it is equivalent to 75/5 = 15 in base 10.

Answer (score 18):

Using brute force of one heavy stroke line, answer could be :

> [image]

Or using correction fluid :

> [image]

Answer (score 15):

The one line to be added is:

> If we define '+' as string concatenation, the following equation holds:

It needs to be added in front of the equation.

Comment: In my opinion, whoever upvotes this answer should also upvote [Naeem Shaikh's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/73899/32339).

Comment: @xhienne: My answer is a play on the wording "one line", so I would say that it is a succinctly different solution.

Comment: Oh, you are right, sorry I missed the subtlety of your answer.

Answer (score 13):

> Add ONLY ONE line (does not have to be straight)

> [image: yee]
>   <sub>(Line is curvy)</sub>

Comment: Very clever but that would be too easy. Nevertheless, (+1) from me :D

Comment: This is the best answer xD $(+1)$

Answer (score 12):

Given 5+5+5=555
You can make the equation true by adding one line (or symbol).

> The angle/ degree symbol.

Where:

> 5+5+5 = ∠555 (or 555°)

Given that:

> the override of ∠555 is 195° (or 15°)).

Therefore:

> 5+5+5 = ∠555 (or 15° = 555°)

Image:

> [image]

[Edit] Added further text to include comments that note how my answer can be written in two ways (where one of those two can be drawn with two lines depending on an individual's way of writing).

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Love the cleverness of this answer and well formatted, keep up the good work!

Comment: You can argue that the angle line is actually two lines.

Comment: You very well could - at that point, it becomes the digression of the viewer and how they personally write/ pen the angle line. Such as how you can write "2," "5," "7," or "8" with one or two pen lines for instance. :)

Comment: Clever one, you could also add one circular line telling : 5+5+5=555°

Comment: this is the best answer so far

Answer (score 6):

> This is already true in javascript, if the value 5 is typecasted to string before the equation.
> `var a = '5'; var result = a + a + a; // produces 555`

Comment: Nice try but not the intended one :D

Comment: In this case, the line could be ` since that denotes code in Markdown. :)  ... though I'm not sure that it works without the matching tick on the end!

Answer (score 5):

I guess this is more probable to add a clarification in the riddle's body rather than be accepted as an answer.

> $5  + 5 + 5 \le 555$

Comment: You have 550 instead of 555, but otherwise, yes this could be a solution.

Answer (score 5):

My try!

> Working modulo $5$, $$5+5+5\equiv555$$ Actually, this works modulo $k$ whenever $k\mid 540$.

Comment: Yes, this can be the answer but I'm still waiting for others to come up with better ones (+1) :D

Comment: Please tell me you have an answer in mind?

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Oh I do myself but I'm sure others have even more

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I don't understand your solution. The symbol you used means 'equivalence' or 'identical to'. How does that work?

Comment: @rhsquared [Congruences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Definition_of_congruence_relation)

Answer (score 2):

> one more solution I would like to post,
> [image]

Comment: Clever but not what I'm looking for :D

Comment: I thought of that, but "5" is not even an equation

Comment: Please avoid posting separate, short answers; instead, merge them together.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire .. two different approach to solve a problem can be two different answers.. it's not one answer, it's just different..

Answer (score 2):

> [image]

Can it be like this ?? I use one line as a border.

Comment: But that won't be a "valid" equation right? I mean you still have unused number outside of the border :D

Comment: @KevinL So? Often you'll see page numbers nearby an equation... do those have to participate in the equation too?

Comment: @Sneftel Interesting find, but unfortunately, it won't be part of the equation :D

Comment: @KevinL That's my point. If it's okay to disregard page numbers, it's okay to disregard stuff outside the box.

Comment: @Sneftel True, well I guess this may count but at the end, the highest voted answer will get the tick :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt:

> [image: Equation Modified]
>
>  So you end up with 5 + 55 = 5 + 55

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   5   
> +   55  = 555
> ```
>
> Using our base 10 (decimal) system when doing sums.
> So the first 5 would become 500, the second 50, and the last is the unit.

Comment: Nice answer mate :D

Comment: This is cool and all, but how is this one line?

Answer (score 0):

> Probably not the answer since i added a dot below the added line. 
>  5 + 5 + 5 != 555

Answer (score 0):

Fine, many creative answers are provided. Here are my two cents based on Xhienne's answer-

> It is true to say that 5 + 5 + 5 = 55 / 5, in  a number system -  with  base *6*

As,

> ,LHS is 15 (base 6) = 11 ( base 10) and RHS is 55 / 5 (base 6) =  11 (base 6) resulting in 11 on both the sides!

Comment: Sorry, but your notation is wrong and painful to read. Also, if you introduce different bases, several other solutions arise. For example $5_{10}+5_{10}+5_{10}={15}_{10}={11}_{14}$

Answer (score -1):

Results in the following equation:

> 5 + 5 + 5 ≠ 555

Comment: No crossing the equal sign :D

Comment: Oops, didn't see that. I guess when I read Notes and Clarification I thought it was an optional read, and as I was so focused on providing "the obvious answer" I didn't even notice. My bad